# Grunt include bower_components in usemin block

Tags: css, gruntjs, bower

I have the following block in my index.html page..

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/style.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/normalize-css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The css files exist correctly in my app structure, but when I run 'grunt build' only the CSS from styles/main.css is included in the resulting styles/style.css file.

I assume I need to tell Grunt to look in the bower_components directory for CSS files? But I'm unsure how to do this?

A copy of my gruntfile.js below...

```
    grunt.initConfig({
      yeoman: yeomanConfig,
      watch: {
        styles: {
          files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
          tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        livereload: {
          options: {
            livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
          },
          files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
          ]
        }
      },
      autoprefixer: {
        options: ['last 1 version'],
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/'
          }]
        }
      },
      connect: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
          options: {
            middleware: function (connect) {
              return [
                lrSnippet,
                mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
              ];
            }
          }
        },
        test: {
          options: {
            middleware: function (connect) {
              return [
                mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                mountFolder(connect, 'test')
              ];
            }
          }
        },
        dist: {
          options: {
            middleware: function (connect) {
              return [
                mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.dist)
              ];
            }
          }
        }
      },
      open: {
        server: {
          url: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
        }
      },
      clean: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            dot: true,
            src: [
              '.tmp',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
              '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
            ]
          }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
      },
      jshint: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        all: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      rev: {
        dist: {
          files: {
            src: [
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      },
      usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
          dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        }
      },
      imagemin: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
          }]
        }
      },
      svgmin: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            src: '{,*/}*.svg',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
          }]
        }
      },
      cssmin: {

      },
      htmlmin: {
        dist: {
          options: {

          },
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: ['*.html', 'views/*.html'],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          }]
        }
      },
      // Put files not handled in other tasks here
      copy: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            src: [
              '*.{ico,png,txt}',
              '.htaccess',
              'bower_components/**/*',
              'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
              'styles/fonts/*'
            ]
          }, {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.tmp/images',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
            src: [
              'generated/*'
            ]
          }]
        },
        styles: {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
      },
      concurrent: {
        server: [
          'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
          'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
          'copy:styles',
          'imagemin',
          'svgmin',
          'htmlmin'
        ]
      },
      karma: {
        unit: {
          configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
          singleRun: true
        }
      },
      cdnify: {
        dist: {
          html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
        }
      },
      ngmin: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
            src: '*.js',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'
          }]
        }
      },
      uglify: {
        dist: {
          files: {
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one of solutions.

```
copy: {

  ...

  styles: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
    dest: '.tmp/',
    src: [
      'styles/{,*/}*.css',
      'bower_components/**/*.css'
    ]
  }
```

The problem is caused beause normalize.css does not exist under .tmp directory, although index.html file says `<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/style.css -->`.
So you need to copy the CSS file (actually all CSS files under bower_components directory in the above case) to .tmp directory.

Alternatively, you can use `@import` statement in styles/main.css (or main.scss?).

Comment: Adding the bower_components to the styles src value didn't resolve the issue. Using @import works however and in this case, a neater solution. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, but had to take into account 'cwd' (current working directory) so that the bower_components directory could be found relative to that location i.e. I had cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles', which meant that I needed to add '../' to the src entry for bower, so '../bower_components/[etc]'

Answer (score 10):

I've solved this in the HTML itself:

```
    <!-- build:css styles/modules.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="not_bower/foo/plugin.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

You just have to generate two files, one with "external" css outside your `app/css` folder, and another with your app CSS.

With this solution you don't have to touch `Gruntfile.js`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Marcal, this worked great for me.  Way simpler than tweaking the Usemin settings. It would be good to make sure those 2 scripts get concatenated as well before revisioning, but 2 files isn't too bad.

Comment: @eriksssss sorry for the delay, I think it's not possible right now, you can only use one alternative path, not multiple (https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#blocks)

Comment: If you are using the Angular generator past v0.9.0, you should also be careful not to put anything between <!-- bower:js --> and <!-- endbower -->, because the new generator uses grunt-wiredep which will overwrite your changes.

Comment: @christang I have this disabled because was buggy for me when I tested it.

Answer (score 9):

Yeoman Angular generators for [versions later than 0.9.0](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/43978f5e7c4e72ca5861744cb642eb1b6a315151/CHANGELOG.md#090-0-2014-06-05) use [grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep) to automate injecting bower dependencies into app/index.html. wiredep looks at the bower.json configurations of each of your dependencies in bower_components and adds hrefs to app/index based on the main property.

For instance, you might have a jquery-ui dependency with a bower.json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "jquery-ui",
  "version": "1.11.1",
  "main": [
    "jquery-ui.js"
  ], ...
}
```

Then when you run grunt, wiredep will auto-inject "jquery-ui.js" into your app/index.html file. Neato!

The problem is that it could be missing a dependency. If you use bower to manage your bower_components directory, you don't want to change the bower.json file in bower_components/jquery-ui since any changes will be wiped if you ever need to rebuild your dependencies.

Instead, you can override the main property in your app bower.json. Instead, you can use [bower overrides](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#bower-overrides):

```
  "overrides": {
    "jquery-ui": {
      "main": [
        "jquery-ui.js",
        "this/was/missing/jquery-ui.css"
      ]
    }
  }
```

This lets you keep your project specific overrides where they belong, in your own app configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much. All solutions specified above didn't work for me but yours did perfectly! In my case, it was for https://github.com/jaysalvat/vegas. Here is what I add in my bower.json:
  "overrides": {
    "vegas": {
      "main": [
        "dist/jquery.vegas.js",
        "dist/jquery.vegas.css"
      ]
    }
  },

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<!-- build:css({app,.tmp}) styles/style.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/normalize-css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/201) for more details